# VS 2010 - Add Service Reference Error

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, wcf-client

[image: H]

As you can see that from the above screenshot, VS 2010 "Add service reference" adds the standard library class as well. I tried using svcutil and we dont want to use svcutil for a while. Any solution for this ?

For your information : I have used "reuse referenced libraries" and selected only the our own data contract library dll which is shared between wcf and client

Note: In the above GQDPService is the namespace for the service.

Comment: Why on earth is the service exposing *string builders*?

Comment: Are you pointing the entire name of the class? GQDPService.StringBuilder or just StringBuilder?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : I am not exposing StringBuilder at all. But We do have used stringbuilder in the service implementation

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this service reference, then I think you'll need to prefix all references to `System.Text.StringBuilder` with `global::` in your project.

```
global::StringBuilder
```

Leave `GQDPService.StringBuilder` as they are.